# SELECT from table INSERTED throws exception "There is no row at position 0" (Index Out of Range Exception)

Tags: c#, .net, triggers, sql-server-2012, clr

I've got a problem with a CLR Trigger developed in Visual Studio 2010 and then deployed in SQL Server 2012.

The trigger fires FOR INSERT, UPDATE and so i have a structure like this in my trigger:

```
...

//TriggerManager is a class that handle the execution of 
//queries and the trigger context connection
using (TriggerManager t = new TriggerManager())
{
    inserted = @"SELECT * FROM INSERTED";

    DataSet lastdoc = new DataSet();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(inserted))
    {
         //The method QueryDataAdapter return a dataset filled with the command cmd.
         lastdoc = t.QueryDataAdapter(cmd);
    }

    //Here i need to store the whole record to use it in
    //further elaborations.
    //And here the execption is raised.
    DataRow insertedRow = lastdoc.Tables[0].Rows[0];
    int docid = (int)insertedRow["field1"];
    string obj = insertedRow["field2"].ToString();


    switch (triggerContext.TriggerAction)
    {
        case TriggerAction.Insert:
            ...
            break;

        case TriggerAction.Update:
            ...
            break;
    }
```

So the problem is that the trigger fires, tries to get the Row[0], but the exeption message is "There is no Row at position 0". But the strange things is that the operations which should be executed by the trigger, are executed anyway (and the DataRow inserted row is necessary for the elaboration).

I tryed to insert a control like

```
if (lastdoc.Tables.Count >0 && lastdoc.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)
{
    ...
}
```

before trying to get the row. But with this control the trigger doesn't perform its operations.

It seems like the trigger fires again after the failure, but why does it find the table INSERTED empty at the (theoretical) first try ?

Comment: You should always be careful to write triggers that can deal with `inserted` containing 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Since all of those situations can arise.

Comment: A trigger should be as simple and lean as possible, avoid long-running tasks and computations. For the same reason, I would avoid writing triggers in SQL-CLR - use proper T-SQL for that task.